# Is it possible to dynamically select a certain option from a select menu in a JSP page?

Tags: html, jsp, tags, html-select

I have a list of records displayed on a JSP page.  The user then can click an 'edit' link to modify any part of those records.  when they click the edit link they are taken to a different JSP page that has all of the input fields for the record (name, rating, price, etc).  the problem is that one of the fields is a select option menu.  How can i dynamically set this select menu to the correct option? its easy for the text fields because its just

```
  value="<%=title%>"
```

but idk what to do for the option menu. help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the passed data with your data  set in that page.

Do something like this

Run a loop. Check

```
if(passedValue==thisValue)
   <option selected=\"selected\"><%=your value%></option> 
else
   <option><%=your value%></option>
```